# C: The remove function removes all files?

Tags: c, chmod, file-handling

I am using something like this:

```
char *file;
file = (char *)malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof(char));
printf("Enter the filename:");
scanf("%s", file);
if(remove(file)) {
   printf("Error while removing");
}
```

I created two files:

```
touch filetobedeleted1.txt
chmod 777 filetobedeleted1.txt

touch filetobedeleted2.txt
chmod 444 filetobedeleted2.txt
```

Now, my program removes both the files but that is not supposed to happen right? Anyone knows what is wrong with the code?

EDIT: Added the code for putting the name into file...

Ok... looks like it all depends on the permissions set on the directory but then is there a way to use file permissions as a check?

Comment: You haven't posted the most important bits of the code-- how and with what exactly are you populating the `file` variable? Are you calling it in a loop? What does the surrounding code look like?

Comment: @tur1ng - No, `remove()` is a standard function. We need his code that builds the filename.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a more complete code snippet.  Specifically, how many times is the remove(file) statement executed by your program, and for which value(s) of 'file'?

Comment: And by the way, I am using the standard remove function call...

Comment: Why are you allocating file twice - once statically and once dynamically ? And why are you passing %c as a format parameter to scanf when it should be %s ?

Comment: Ah... guess lots of coffee... Sorry.. it was a typo!

Comment: What happens when someone wants to delete a file that has a space in its name? `scanf` will not work for you in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under POSIX filesystem semantics, the permission check used for deleting a file is whether you can write to the directory that the file is in; *not* whether you have write permission on the file itself.

(If the directory has the sticky bit set, then you must also be the owner of the file - `/tmp` uses this).

Comment: So does it mean that on a web server, if the admin is careless in removing the write permissions on the directory, then a simple "DELETE" command can mess things up?

Comment: No, because the userspace tools like `rm` usually ask you to confirm if you want to remove a file without write permissions (cf. `rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `x'?`).  The presumption is if you are writing a C program, then you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Removing a file only needs write access on the directory.

Strictly speaking, what you're removing is a reference to the file, a hardlink. The file itself will not be deleted until all links to the file are gone.

Try it with the rm command!

Answer (score 1):

`remove()` calls `unlink()`, and according to `man 2 unlink`, that only needs write permissions to the **parent** directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getumask()` function and give it a check before calling `remove()`.